# How to get mic activity for each stream in opentok

Tags: javascript, webrtc, opentok

I have problem about how to get mic activity for each stream with OpenTok.
I am working with PHP and OpenTok.js for this.

Here is my current code.

```
    ......
        var subscribers;

        session.on("streamCreated", function(event) {
           var subscriber = session.subscribe(event.stream, 'elementId', {
              insertMode: 'append',
              width: 100%,
              height: 100%
           })
           subscribers[subscriber.id] = subscriber;
           for(var user in subscribers) {
              console.log(subscribers[user].getAudioVolume());
           }
        });

..........
```

I tried like this, but always result is 100.

Who can solve this?
Please help me.
Yuri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var movingAvg = null;
subscriber.on('audioLevelUpdated', function(event) {
  if (movingAvg === null || movingAvg <= event.audioLevel) {
movingAvg = event.audioLevel;
  } else {
movingAvg = 0.7 * movingAvg + 0.3 * event.audioLevel;
  }

  // 1.5 scaling to map the -30 - 0 dBm range to [0,1]
  var logLevel = (Math.log(movingAvg) / Math.LN10) / 1.5 + 1;
  logLevel = Math.min(Math.max(logLevel, 0), 1);
  document.getElementById('subscriberMeter').value = logLevel;
});
```